# Date issue? (Not DIY question)

Tags: discussion

Is there a date issue with the system?  I just saw a new post (about water remaining in a Kenmore washing machine) that the question list said was posted 42 min ago. When I viewed the question  the date said it was posted in 2017, more than 2 years ago. Several other questions had similar incongruities. It's currently 4:19am CDT May 13, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

The date stamp on the front page is from when the question was last active, and answering the question is an activity. In front of that time, you will see "asked", "modified", or "answered" indicating what type of activity there was.

You can change the sort order with the tabs at the top of the page, e.g. here's the questions sorted by most recently asked: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest